# Откуда докер берет пакеты Python?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Если докер содержи команду сборки Python и команду на установку пакетов из **requirements.txt**.

Откуда он будет качать пакеты, которые прописаны в **requirements.txt**? Из докер-хаба или из сторонних источников?

Comment: В docker hub хранятся только Docker образы, все остальной качается из других репозиториев, я точно не знаю что используется в python, но скорее всего - pypi.org

Comment: `requirements.txt` обрабатывает  [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). По-умолчанию он берёт пакеты из  [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/)